# Docker Compose TERM environment variable not set in airgeddon image

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

That's my docker-compose.yml file, which contains a reference to airgeddon Docker image.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  airg:
    container_name: airg
    image: v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=0
    volumes:
      - .docker/io:/io
      - .docker/plugins:/opt/airgeddon/plugins
```

When running this project it shows a loop in the terminal prompt, which always refreshes the content ( Interface selection menu selection), making it impossible to use.

It informs me that `tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified` and `| TERM environment variable not set.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the wiki](https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon/wiki/Docker%20Linux), it's recommended to use an interactive terminal session to use this image. With the `docker run` command, that's the `-it` flags.

To do this with docker-compose, you'd add these settings to your file:

```yaml
    image: v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Also, you might've meant to set `DISPLAY=:0`, with the `:`? The wiki points out that that's the default DISPLAY variable if so, so you may not need to set it at all.